# Virtualbox firewall issue?

Tags: virtualbox, remote-desktop

I have followed this tutorial http://ubuntuguide.net/enable-remote-desktop-in-virtual-machinevirtualbox-guest and still cannot remote into the Windows XP desktop I have installed, it tries to connect but times out. I have this running through a home network.

My question is, do I need to do anything in terms of firewall settings in Ubuntu to allow rdp to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the virtual machine to Bridged in the network settings, installed TightVNC viewer and I could connect with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need nothing special.

Note that you should connect to your Ubuntu machine to access the Virtual Machine that way, not to the guest. Something like:

```
rdesktop localhost
```

should work.